# How to make the bot detects for a reaction on every message on a channel?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the bot detects always for reactions to execute a code (here I'm trying to create a channel by reacting).

I tried to use Reaction Collector but it has a timer, and it can not be used for every messages.

I need an example please, i really tried many things and i didn't find anything useful on docs.

Comment: Perhaps a better place to ask would be the Discord developer help server. There's a link to it here: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro#getting-help

Comment: I know about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to use Reaction Collector but it has a timer...

My apologies for this misconception; I was mistaken when I previously implied that collectors are restricted to a time limit.

According to the docs, omitting the `time` option defaults to no time limit (see [`CollectorOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions)). Therefore, this example should continue to look for the user's reaction until the bot stops.

```js
message.channel.send('React with .')
  .then(m => {
    const filter = (reaction, user) => user.id === message.author.id && reaction.emoji.name === '';
    const collector = m.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 1 });

    collector.on('collect', () => {
      message.clearReactions();
      message.edit('You did it!');
    });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

However, as mentioned, if the bot stops, the collector will stop. There's no easy way around this. If you truly want infinite collection, the only solution I see is storing a list of messages and corresponding collectors in a database (or json file), and applying them again to existing messages in the client's `ready` event.

Comment: Yes, I know, and I have some existing specific msgs, i want to make members able to create voice channels when reacting, for each msg there is a different channel to create, i will not going to make it automatic like displays that msg when execute a command, so yeah, the only thing that i should do is getting the msgs IDs, and i will put them on "if", so yeah that's good to me, but i still don't know how to make it happens.

Comment: Do you mean that the messages have already been sent, and you want to collect reactions to them?

Comment: Exactly, or better: every messages have already been sent on a specific channel, so we don't have to get every channel ID.

Comment: Is it okay to send the messages again, or do you need to use the existing ones?

Comment: And we can make the msg content as the channel name

Comment: some existing embeds on a channel called "create voice channels"

Comment: So, any idea ??